# Classic ADO and Table-Valued Parameters in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, vb6, ado

Is there some way to pass a table-valued parameter to a stored procedure in SQL Server via classic ADO?

Comment: What version of SQL server? Until 2005, a table variable as a parameter for an SP is impossible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thought they were new in 2008?

Anyway, I think the answer is going to be no, I doubt there's a DataTypeEnum value that you'll be able to bend to your needs.

So if I may suggest an alternative, I guess what you want to do is pass some sort of structured data into the stored procedure. I have done this before in ADO using XML:

- define the parameter in the stored proc as type xml
- define the parameter in ADO as type adLongVarChar with a length = len(xml) + 1

I know it's not what you wanted, but it's a method that works

Answer (score 7):

Classic ADO is COM and OLE and the SQL Native Client supports Table Valued Parameters over OleDB, see [Table-Valued Parameters (OLE DB)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510472.aspx). One would have to get its hand dirty and code straight to the OleDB interfaces (in C/C++).

Also TVPs are only in SQL 2008, so you won't be able to use them in SQL 2005.

BTW, for completness here is the [Table Valued Parameters (ODBC)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522663.aspx) reference, for the ODBC nostalgics out there...