# Handling multiple list box options by user Interface as input for store precedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

VB6 user interface have multiple types of data selection , like list boxes, combo boxes etc, based on which user refreshes and gets the data, moreover most of it are not compulsory parameter.
My solution: Creating tables dbo. and on refresh button deletes the existing data and populates these table based on the selections made above as mentioned, then in store procedure retrieving data from these temp tables 
example below:

```
 select * from jobs where jobs in (select distinct jobs from dbo.tempJobs)
```

I am sure this is not the right way because for different type of list boxes different tables are performing deletes and inserts then using these tables in store procedure.

So what is the standard way of this type of work ?? 
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you investigated Table Valued Parameters? Sorry I have no explicit examples but I think that's what you're after.

You don't mention which version of SQL Server - you need SQL 2008, but here are some examples:

[Classic ADO and Table-Valued Parameters in Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883852/classic-ado-and-table-valued-parameters-in-stored-procedure)

http://geekswithblogs.net/Bunch/archive/2011/11/03/using-table-valued-parameters.aspx

Comment: BINGO !!! Yes this what i was looking for ! Thanks for understanding my requirement !!!
Yes i didnt mentioned sql version because i wanted to know the hint of using standard way of performing this task !
So the idea is to use array as parameter in store procedures, however as arrays are not supported in SP's hence table valued parameters comes in the picture !!!
Yes we recently upgraded to SQL server 2008 apart from using this table valued parameters is there other way?? May be using XML something etc, just want to know because this is for only sql 2008 only :-(

Comment: I don't do much coding any more but I do a lot of reading and this method has come up more often than using XML. In fact I believe people used to use XML as a workaround before this method came along.

Answer (score 0):

If those tables (jobs, tempjobs) are not huge there is nothing wrong in your query. But you can use;

- `Object.AddItemitem, Index` - For adding items at runtime
- `Object.RemoveItem index` - For removing items at runtime

Here is the link
http://visualbasic.freetutes.com/learn-vb6/lesson9.html

I hope I understand your question correct.

Comment: @Faith thanks for reply, for adding or removing items at runtime is not a problem, what i need is form any interface how to handle multiple list boxes data to be use in store procedures.

Comment: I see. Anyway ElectricLlama answered your question as far as I can see.